# Where to ask a Meteor question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, closed-questions

The [Meteor doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#resources) links to Stack Overflow. I am surprised [4 out of the 5 top voted Meteor questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor?sort=votes&pageSize=5) are closed. As a Meteor newbie, those questions are exactly what I am going to ask.

Where should I ask a Meteor questions similar to the above top 5?

Comment: Stack overflow questions are all about "how to do something", would your questions be of that form? The closed questions are all closed because they are too broad or opinion based. As you can see other meteor questions were well recieved. Often high voted closed questions were once on topic but no longer are

Comment: Well, those specific closed questions were not closed because they were about Meteor. They were closed because they were off-topic for Stack Overflow, regardless of what tag was used.

Comment: @RichardTingle Is there a site for _broad or opinion based_ questions?

Comment: If you have specific programming questions that don't try to gage opinion or ask broad questions about security, then you are just fine. There are [more than 3500 *open* questions about Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmeteor%5D+closed%3A0) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ohho: Sure, but its not Stack Overflow. Forums, mailinglists, chatrooms, all would probably welcome such discussion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, can you share pointers to some of those forums?

Comment: @ohho: Not really, no. But the [page you linked to yourself](http://docs.meteor.com/#resources) lists two mailinglists already.

Answer (score 2):

The actual SO community rules about questions are, that you shouldn't ask similar questions to those you've linked, because they are **too broad** or **opinion based**. Such questions were such upvoted because their open-endness attracted a lot of activity, but they are not considered a good fit form Q&A anymore.

Of course, [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) questions are on-topic, as long they [meet the criteria for good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: `meteor` is on-topic. I'd like to know where to ask the _bad_ questions, i.e. "similar to the above top 5" as stated in my question, which are not welcome on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

That self-same document mentions a couple of Google Groups that they use. They even say that [meteor-talk@googlegroups.com](http://groups.google.com/group/meteor-talk) is for general questions.